# My GitHub Action's GitHub API calls start failing after a period of time

Tags: github-actions

Yesterday I successfully ran this GitHub action several times, but now it is failing with an HTTP Not Found error.  If I make the same REST call to the URL in Postman  https://api.github.com/repos/RobotOpsPlayground/scottTest5/issues/4 I get back the expected JSON results. I do not understand what has changed, does anyone have an idea?

So far, I have recreated and am using a new GitHub personal token, which has the same permissions as the one that was working.  I have copied the code into a new repo and encountered the same problem.

This is the output from the action's execution:

```
Run ./.github/actions/route_issue/
  with:
    myToken: ***
    myOwner: RobotOpsPlayground
    myRepo: RobotOpsPlayground/scottTest5
    myKnownLabels: repo-request, team-request, member-request, triage
    myDefaultLabel: triage
    myIssueNumber: 0
issueNumber 4
owner RobotOpsPlayground
repo RobotOpsPlayground/scottTest5
token ***
getting /repos/RobotOpsPlayground/scottTest5/issues/4 details from github 
"GET /repos/RobotOpsPlayground/scottTest5/issues/4
sync function called for /repos/:repo/issues/:issueNumber
failing due to HttpError: Not Found -- Not Found
Error: Not Found
```

And here is the action.yaml

```yaml
name: 'route_issue'
description: 'pull some info from an issue'
inputs:
  myToken:  
    description: 'github token'
    required: true
  myOwner:  
    description: 'github owner|organization'
    required: true
    default: 'RobotOpsPlayground'
  myRepo: 
    description: 'github repo'
    required: true
```

And a part of the action's index.js

```js
async function run() {

  const myToken = core.getInput('myToken');
  const myOwner = core.getInput('myOwner');
  const myRepo = core.getInput('myRepo');
  const myIssueNumber = github.context.issue.number;
    
  // get issue details by looking up its issue number
  console.log(`getting /repos/${myRepo}/issues/${myIssueNumber} details from github `);
  let req = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/repos/:repo/issues/:issueNumber',
      headers: { authorization: `token ${myToken}` },
      repo: myRepo,
      issueNumber: myIssueNumber,
      log: "debug"
  };


  const result = await request req
  console.log("past getting issue")
  issue = result['data'];
  console.log(`my issue ${issue}`)
  if (issue.state !== 'open') {
    console.log("issue was not open")
  } else {
    console.log("processing issue");
  }
}
```

And the GitHub workflow

```yaml
name: route_issue

on:
  issues:
    types: [opened]

jobs:
  route_issue:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    outputs:
      issueNumber: ${{ steps.route_issue.outputs.issueNumber }}
      requestType: ${{ steps.route_issue.outputs.requestType }}  
    steps:
    - id: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
     
    - id: route_issue
      uses: ./.github/actions/route_issue/
      with:
        myToken: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN3 }}
        myOwner: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
        myRepo: ${{ github.repository }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, due to my error

The code block

```
  let req = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/repos/:repo/issues/:issueNumber',
      headers: { authorization: `token ${myToken}` },
      repo: myRepo,
      issueNumber: myIssueNumber,
      log: "debug"
  };
```

had a mistake, which I am not sure why it worked before, but anyway the issue was that the `myRepo` variable contained the value `my-organization/my-reponame`.  When the req structure was passed into the `request` call

```
  const result = await request(req)
```

the `@octokit/request` library I am using was encoding the :repo parameter to be `my-organization@2FA/my-reponame`, replacing the '/' with @2FA.  This character replacement made the url generated invalid.

The fix was to split the myRepo variable on the '/' and pass both parts to the request library.

```
       let org_repo = myRepo.split('/')

       let req = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/repos/:org/:repo/issues/:issueNumber',
          headers: { authorization: `token ${myToken}` },
          org: org_repo[0],
          repo: org_repo[1],
          issueNumber: myIssueNumber,
          log: "debug"
      };
```

The generated URL is now correct, and the request calls are working.